# Extract OTP from message in Retrivel API(auto SMS verification)

Tags: java, android, google-api, sms-verification

Iam using Google Retriver API for automatic sms verification, now everthings works fine. 
Iam receiving sms message from Broadcast receiver class.
This is my sms message..

> <#> Waahan: Your verification code is:1453 jtN03jdhD6p

**I want to extract only the otp from the message..**

SMSBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

            switch(status.getStatusCode())
            {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);

                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched, but every one is using telephony.. iam using retrievel API..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: you want just "1453 jtN03jdhD6p" right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
 String OTP = message.substring(message.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
```

*possible using SubString(Start,End) Function*

Comment: if you get your answer so approve it... Thank you